# Saving output in a gdb Feature dataset in ArcMap Modelbuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, arcgis-10.5, feature-dataset

I'm using ArcMap 10.5.

I've got a model with a bunch of processes related to different topics such as ROADS, URBAN SQUARES, PARKINGS, etc. I'm currently working from a geodatabase that stores all the results in the same place and sometimes it's hard to find the outputs of a particular topic.

What I'd like to do is to store each output in is corresponding Feature dataset, meaning roads geoprocessing outputs will go to the ROADS Feature dataset and the same with the rest.

I thought that'd be something easy but turns out that when I set the save path to a Feature dataset, that process in particular returns this error:

[image]

This works:

```
C:\geodb.gdb\INDEX_FULLA
```

Whereas this does not work:

```
C:\geodb.gdb\RESULTS\INDEX_FULLA
```

This occurs only with raster outputs. I can't select the feature dataset when navigating and if I write it manually then the error is returned. I have checked the CRS and they are the same.

Also add that I'm trying to save in an empty Feature dataset, it didnd't even have any previous information.

Is there any way to be able to save raster outputs in Feature datasets?

Comment: What exact error is returned? Feature datasets have coordinate reference compatibility constraints. Please [Edit] the question

Comment: You may be running into the situation where you already have output by the same name elsewhere in the GDB which is not allowed (regardless of it being in a separate feature dataset or outside of the feature dataset(s). Without the exact error, that is just a guess.

Comment: Hi there, I added the error it returns to the question.

Comment: Seems the problem is only with raster outputs: when navigating I can't choose any Feature dataset to save into, and if written manually then the process returns the error I added in the question. I have checked the coordinate systems and they match. Vector saving seems to work fine, I had some missmatches betwen coordinate systems. I have updated my question to fit the situation.

Comment: Doesn't "feature" imply vector data? I've never seen a raster inside a FDS. There are raster datasets in 10.6 you could look into, but that won' help you keep all your "ROADS" data together in one dataset.